# javascript, a little coding help, cant figure this out

Tags: javascript

Everything below works fine, except that the form doesnt get submitted... it seems the problem lies in the 'x.onchange' event... any tips?

```
 var form = document.forms['pic_form'];
 var x=document.createElement("input");
 x.type="file";
 x.name="pic_file2";
 x.id="pic_file2";
 x.size="35";
 x.onchange="pic_form_function(form, 1);";
 var z=document.getElementById("pic_file2");
 z.parentNode.replaceChild(x, z);
```

here is the function called:

```
    pic_form_function(formName, nr){ if (nr==1){formName.submit(); }}
```

It wont submit, but it DOES get replaced and all... help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
x.onchange="pic_form_function(form, 1);";
```

with

```
x.onchange = function () { pic_form_function(form, 1); }
```

which is a

function expression (function operator)

A function expression is similar to and has the same syntax as a function declaration

```
function [name]([param] [, param] [..., param]) {
   statements
}
```

**name**

```
The function name. Can be omitted, in which case the function becomes known 
as an anonymous function.
```

**param**

```
The name of an argument to be passed to the function. A function can have 
up to 255 arguments.
```

**statements**

```
The statements which comprise the body of the function.
```

Also read

[Javascript anonymous functions](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
x.onchange = function(){
               pic_form_function(form, 1);
             };
```

for I never trust assigning events with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the keyword **`function`** before your declaration this should read

```
function pic_form_function(formName, nr){ if (nr==1){formName.submit(); }}
```

Check here for a working example

http://jsbin.com/uvehe

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x.onchange="pic_form_function(document.forms['pic_form'], 1);";
```